# Finding files by creation time of another file

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs

What I need to do is find files by the creation time of another file. For example if i create a file at 9am and later i wanted to find all the files created 1 hour after it or 1 hour before it. How would i do that?

I've tried experimenting with "-newer" whilst using "find" but I think "xargs" is what i need to be using.

Thanks

Comment: On linux the file creation time is not stored, only access, modification and change times (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/get-file-created-creation-time). Does your requirements still hold if you substitute 'creation time' for i.e. 'modification time'?

Comment: Yes that would be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is ooooold, but since I was looking for the same thing...
Here's a oneliner version, basically using the same approach as above:

Modified at least one hour after:

```
find . -newermt "$(date -d "$(stat -c %y reference_file) + 1 hour")"
```

Modified one hour before or more:

```
find . -not -newermt "$(date -d "$(stat -c %y reference_file) - 1 hour")"
```

Modified within the timespan from one hour before to one hour after

```
find . -newermt "$(date -d "$(stat -c %y reference_file) - 1 hour")" -not -newermt "$(date -d "$(stat -c %y reference_file) + 1 hour")"
```

Replace `reference_file` with the file of your choice. You can of course also use othe timespans than `1 hour`

### How it works

`stat -c %y reference_file` will return the modification time.

`date -d "[...] + 1 hour"` will manupulate the date string to one hour later.

`find . -newermt "[...]"` will find files with modification time (`m`) newer than given time (`t`)

All this requires GNU find 4.3.3 or greater (for `-newerXY`) and GNU date (to support `-d` and the complex date strings)

Answer (score 0):

After looking at this I found a way to do this, although it is not the nicest solution as it requires integer arithmetic to be done on time.

The idea is to take the seconds since Unix epoch (aka Unix time) from your reference file, do some integer arithmetic on this to get your offset time (one hour before, or after in your example). Then you use find with the `-newer` parameter.

Example code:

```
# Get the mtime of your reference file in unix time format, 
# assumes 'reference_file' is the name of the file you're using as a benchmark
reference_unix_time=$(ls -l --time-style=+%s reference_file | awk '{ print $6 }')

# Offset 1 hour after reference time
let unix_time_after="$reference_unix_time+60*60"

# Convert to date time with GNU date, for future use with find command
date_time=$(date --date @$unix_time_after '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

# Find files (in current directory or below)which are newer than the reference 
# time + 1hour
find . -type f -newermt "$date_time"
```

For your example of file created upto one hour before the reference file you could use

```
# Offset 1 hour before reference time
let unix_time_before="$reference_unix_time-60*60"

# Convert to date time with GNU date...
date_time=$(date --date @$unix_time_before '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')

# Find files (in current directory or below which were generated 
# upto 1 hour before the reference file
find . -type f -not -newermt "$date_time"
```

Note that all the above is based on the last modification time of files.

The above has been tested with GNU Find (4.5.10), GNU Date (8.15) and GNU Bash (4.2.37).